# Write a program that reads a short string and a longer string and checks if the longer string starts with the letters of the short string. Use strncmp

Tags: c, c-strings, function-call, strlen, strncmp

I need help getting this code to work. Could someone tell me how to properly use strncmp and how to get this to work?

- Example:  Enter first string: john
- Enter second string: johnson
- johnson does start with john

This is my code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include<string.h>  
int main()  
{  
   char str1[20];   
   char str2[20];    
   int value;   
   printf("Enter the first string right here: ");  
   scanf("%s",str1);  
   printf("Enter the second string right here: ");  
   scanf("%s",str2);  
    
   value=strncmp(str1,str2);  
   if(value==0)  
   printf("Your strings are the same");  
   else  
   printf("Your strings are not same");
  
   return 0;  
  }
```

This is what my error code is below

````
main.c:13:27: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 3, have 2
   value=strncmp(str1,str2);  
         ~~~~~~~          ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [<builtin>: main.o] Error 1
exit status 2 ```
````

Comment: Did you read the error message?  It is telling you that strncmp needs 3 arguments.  Read the documentation of strncmp, and don't confuse it with strcmp.

Comment: `int strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n);` : compares only the first (at most) n bytes of s1 and s2.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `strcmp` (note the lack of `n`)?

Comment: Also note that I can easily break your program, by entering a string longer than 19 characters. You need to protect yourself against that, for example by imposing a limit in your `scanf` format strings, like `"%19s"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling the function strncmp

```
value=strncmp(str1,str2);
```

you should check that `str1` is indeed is not less than `str2` or vice versa because in your program it is unclear where the user entered a more shorter string and where he entered a more larger string.

But in any case the function `strncmp` expects three arguments.

At least you have to write

```
value=strncmp(str1,str2, strlen( str2 ));
```

The function is declared like

```
int strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n);
```

You could write for example

```
size_t n1 = strlen( str1 );
size_t n2 = strlen( str2 );

value = strncmp( str1, str2,  n2 < n1 ? n2 : n1 );
```

Also the text in the calls of printf does not satisfy the assignment

```
printf("Your strings are the same"); 
printf("Your strings are not same");
```

You are not determining whether two strings are equal. You need to determine whether one string contains another string in its beginning.